# Java generated classes using xjc does not generates default no args Constructor

Tags: java, jar, xjc, jaxb2-maven-plugin, xsd-1.1

Java classes generated form xsd using the xjx plug don't seem to generate the default no args constructors.[image]

The Generated class is missing the default public NewStudent(){} constructor.[image]

Any idea how it can be achieved?

Comment: Why should it, as the default constructor on its own has no added value to your class?

Comment: Every generated .class file should contain the default constructor automatically as long as there is no other constructor (which I did not see). I cannot imagine that xjc failted there. And you can do `new NewStudent()`.

Comment: There are no constructors in that class. That means the default constructor is implicitly present.

Comment: @Smutje I am using a bean mapper plugin called dozer which requires the presence of the default constructor to instantiate classes on its own.

so I need the default constructor

Comment: Yeah, but the default constructor is, as its name suggests, present by default. Just write `new NewStudent()` and compile it.

Comment: @JoopEggen- the generated class files don't contain that. I just checked. Plus I can do NewStudent(), but this is just an example, I have an XSD with approx 30 classes with more to follow getting added up in the future.

Comment: You are aware that the default constructor is present as long as you don't have another, explicit constructor?